# install php, apache and zend framework

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, zend-framework2

i am new to php,
 and i want to install it on my windows 7 ultimate, 32-bit machine.
please help how to *install* php along with *apache*
 and how to create simple program using zend framework.
i found this forum

```
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?651571-Installing-PHP-5-3-and-Apache-HTTP-Server-on-Windows-7
```

but there is no *`php5apache2_2.dll`* file in my php directory.

i also find this

```
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/zend-framework-from-scratch/
```

There is no include directory in my php folder.
I download *`PHP 5.3 (5.3.28) VC9 x86 Non Thread Safe`*
from `http://windows.php.net/download/`

Comment: Maybe use pre-made one-click package like XAMPP http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html Later just start reading and following tutorial which will show yo basics of ZendFramework http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html or http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

If you are new to PHP, and you do not have experience with installing server software, then you should probably go with a ready-to-use solution. Setting up open source server software, *especially* on Windows, tends to be quite complicated and time consuming.

On Windows 7 you can use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html). They are both server bundles that you can install, like any other program, and then use immediately.

Also, if you are completely new to PHP then you should use some time on actually learning it, before you start using Zend. This applies to most programming languages; not just PHP.

Comment: But i have to run program in zend. i dnt want to use any other framework.

Comment: I cannot stop you, but I would highly recommend that you use some time on learning PHP (the language) before you start using Zend (the framework).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install WAMP server OR XAMPP server application into your system both has Apache server,Mysql database, PHPMyadmin . [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)
OR [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Answer (score 0):

Try wamp or lamp, depending of your development environment. Forget about Zend framework at the first beginning.

Put index.php in your www/ directory after you install wamp/lamp, open browser and point it to localhost/index.php and start learn about objects, patterns, data types, HTTP and REST.

glhf :)

Answer (score 0):

get the zend skeleton setup 
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication

download setup

I am explaining XAMPP SERVER

set Environment variable  php path like  PATH = c:/xampp/php;

restart system

copy zend skeleton app in htdocs folder(rename demo)

open command line
c:\xampp\htdocs\demo> php composer.phar self-update
c:\xampp\htdocs\demo>php composer.phar install

Now zend application install successfully
if more info

follow this link
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html